# Checking if contained object has changed

Tags: python

I am working on creating a module with a class that acts as a container for a list of another created class. Is there a way for the container class to be able to tell if any of the objects it contains has changed?

Here is an example:

```
class Part:
    def __init__(self, size):
         self.part_size = size

class Assembly:
    def __init__(self, *parts):
        self.parts = list(parts)  # `parts` are all Part() objects
        self.update()

    def update(self):
        self.assy_size = 0
        for each in self.parts:
            self.assy_size += each.part_size

    def __getitem__(self, key):
        return self.parts[key]
```

This is what I get if I try to change any of the `Part` properties in the `Assembly`:

```
>>>x = Part(1)
>>>y = Part(1)
>>>z = Part(1)
>>>u = Assembly(x, y, z)
>>>u.assy_size
3
>>>u[0].part_size = 4
>>>u.assy_size
3
```

I know that I can create additional methods that will call the `update` method if I replace, delete, or add `Part` objects to the `Assembly`, but is there any way to have the `Assembly` notified if any of the contained `Part` properties have changed?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The answer is in your question. Use a **property**.

```
class Part:
    _size = 0
    assembly = None

    @property
    def part_size(self):
        return self._size

    @part_size.setter
    def part_size(self, value):
        self._size = value
        if self.assembly:  # only notify if an Assembly is set
            self.assembly.update()

    def set_assembly(self, assembly):
        self.assembly = assembly

    def __init__(self, size):             
         self.part_size = size

class Assembly:
    def __init__(self, *parts):
        self.parts = list(parts)  # `parts` are all Part() objects
        for part in self.parts:
            part.set_assembly(self)  # reference to self needed to notify changes
        self.update()

    def update(self):
        self.assy_size = 0
        for each in self.parts:
            self.assy_size += each.part_size
```

In this version of `Assembly` the constructor sets a reference on the `Part` to itself. This way it can update the assembly when the `part_size` changes. Use it as the example in your question.

```
>>>x = Part(1)
>>>y = Part(1)
>>>z = Part(1)
>>>u = Assembly(x, y, z)
>>>u.assy_size
3
>>>u[0].part_size = 4
>>>u.assy_size
6
```

Comment: this might be sufficient if a part is always bound to an assembly, as it now has a depenency on it. If that is not desirable, something similar can be achieved using an observer

Comment: That's the problem I'm having: in my implementation, the "`Part`" is not always bound to the "`Assembly`".

Comment: You can register the assembly in the `Part`, when you "attach" it to the assembly.

Comment: Bear with me: in the case above, it appears that the `Assembly` object itself is being passed to the `Part` instance in the `__init__` method. How would that work if I want the `Part` to be contained in the `Assembly` and not the other way around? I want the `Part` to be `Assembly`-agnostic.

Comment: If you want the `Assembly` to be notified something has happend, you *have to* call some method on the object. Therefore you need a reference for that object. This is why the `Part` constructor takes the `assembly` in the constructor. I write more code to my answer

Comment: Ah, okay. That seems to work, but now I am a little confused as to how the `Part` accepts the `assembly` as a reference and not as an object.

Comment: You almost always pass a reference in Python code, not the object itself. You can think of them as the same for now, but look up the difference for a deeper understanding. The code I posted works like you wanted if I understood your question correctly.

Comment: Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 0):

If `update` isn't an expensive operation (in your example it isn't, but maybe in reality you have thousands of parts), you could calculate the size ad-hoc using a property:

```
class Assembly:
    def __init__(self, *parts):
        self.parts = list(parts)

    @property
    def assy_size(self):
        result = 0
        for each in self.parts:
            result += each.part_size
        return result
```

which can be accessed the same way: `assembly.assy_size`.

The calculation can also be simplified:

```
    @property
    def assy_size(self):
        return sum(part.part_size for part in self.parts)
```

Comment: This is the cleaner way to calculate `assy_size` property. However the question asks for " ... [a] way to have the Assembly notified...".

Comment: Unfortunately, the `update` method I am using will become quite expensive over the number of iterations I need to use it. Nearly all of the `Assembly` properties in my case are interdependent on the properties of both the `Part` objects and their arrangment in the `Assembly` itself. I need them to be able to talk to each other.